# what is the optimal way to show differences between two data sets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to show differences  of two different datasets in and efficient way. I need to support Hadoop.  I have tried the following methods I now but none have been optimal for Hadoop

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    System.setProperty("hadoop", "C:\\Users\\7777777\\App\\SparkHadoop\\);
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","name") 
    //val sc = new SparkContext()
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config("warehouse.dir","C:\\Users\\777777\\workspace\\OracleSparkImport\\warehouse").appName("name").getOrCreate();
   import spark.implicits._
    val baseConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("C:/Users/7777/workspace/OracleSparkReport/resources_new/application.properties")).withFallback(baseConfig)
    val dbConfigs = config.getConfig("db");
    val connectionStr = dbConfigs.getString("connectionstr");

       print(dbConfigs);
       var queryStrKey2 = "q2" ;
       var queryStr2 = dbConfigs.getString(queryStrKey2);
       var queryStrKey3 = "q3";
       var queryStr3 = dbConfigs.getString(queryStrKey3);

       var query2 = "(" + queryStr2 + ") rep";
       var query3 = "(" + queryStr3 + ") rep3";

    var df2 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url", connectionStr)
            .option("dbtable",query2)
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
            .load();

    var df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url", connectionStr)
            .option("dbtable",query3)
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
            .load();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I dont understand what do you mean by "optimal" one way is like below.

***Option 1 :***

---

***If you want to find schema differences between 2 dataframes***

```
/**
    * getAllSchemaDiff
    *
    * @param schema1 Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)]
    * @param schema2 Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)]
    * @return Map[String, (Option[(DataType, Boolean)], Option[(DataType, Boolean)])]
    */
  def getAllSchemaDiff(schema1: Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)],
                       schema2: Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)]
                      ): Map[String, (Option[(DataType, Boolean)], Option[(DataType, Boolean)])] = {

    val common = ((schema1.keySet).intersect(schema2.keySet)).map(_.toLowerCase).toList.distinct
    LOGGER.info(" common columns are   " + common.mkString("\n"))

    val distinctkeys = ((schema1.keys) ++ (schema2.keys)).map(_.toLowerCase).toList.distinct
    LOGGER.info("distinctkeys - > " + distinctkeys)
    distinctkeys.flatMap { columnName: String =>
      val schema1FieldOpt: Option[(DataType, Boolean)] = schema1.get(columnName)
      val schema2FieldOpt: Option[(DataType, Boolean)] = schema2.get(columnName)

      if (schema1FieldOpt == schema2FieldOpt) None
      else Some(columnName -> (schema1FieldOpt, schema2FieldOpt))
    }.toMap
  }
```

*where getMapFromSchema is...*

```
 /**
        * getMapFromSchema -Extract relevant information: name (key), type & nullability (values) of columns
        *
        * @param df
        * @return
        */
      def getMapFromSchema(df: DataFrame): Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)] = {
        val a: Seq[(String, (DataType, Boolean))] = df.schema.map { structField: StructField =>
          structField.name.toLowerCase -> (structField.dataType, structField.nullable)
        }.toList

        a.toMap
      }
```

***if you want find column wise differences :***

```
/**
    * columnWiseDifferences - finds columnWise differences between 2 dataframes one is source and another is target
    *
    * @param sourceDataFrame
    * @param targetDataFrame
    * @return
    */

  def columnWiseDifferences(sourceDataFrame: DataFrame, targetDataFrame: DataFrame) = {
    val columns = sourceDataFrame.schema.fields.map(_.name)
    //    LOGGER.info("source schema")
    //    sourceDataFrame.printSchema
    //    LOGGER.info("target schema")
    //    targetDataFrame.printSchema
    LOGGER.info("Source except target")
    var selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => sourceDataFrame.select(col).except(targetDataFrame.select(col)))

    // columns contains different values.
    selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {
      if (diff.count > 0) diff.show
    })

    selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => targetDataFrame.select(col).except(sourceDataFrame.select(col)))
    LOGGER.info("target except source")

    // columns contains different values.
    selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {
      if (diff.count > 0) diff.show
    })
  }
```

Full example :

```
pacakage com.examples

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructField}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

/**
  * @author Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object ComparisionUtil {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
    logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName(this.getClass.getName).master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df1 = Seq(
      (1, "Ram", ""),
      (2, "william peck", ""),
      (3, "peck", "")
    ).toDF("id", "name", "grade")
    val df2 = Seq(
      (1, "Ram", 3),
      (2, "william peck", 3),
      (3, "peck", 3)
    ).toDF("id", "name", "grade")
    val diffMap = getAllSchemaDiff(getMapFromSchema(df1), getMapFromSchema(df2))
        LOGGER.info("schema differences are  " + diffMap)

    val srcNTgtDataFrames = getDataFramesWithCommonColumns(df1, df2)
    columnWiseDifferences(srcNTgtDataFrames._1, srcNTgtDataFrames._2)
  }

  private[this] val LOGGER: org.slf4j.Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  /**
    * getAllSchemaDiff
    *
    * @param schema1 Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)]
    * @param schema2 Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)]
    * @return Map[String, (Option[(DataType, Boolean)], Option[(DataType, Boolean)])]
    */
  def getAllSchemaDiff(schema1: Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)],
                       schema2: Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)]
                      ): Map[String, (Option[(DataType, Boolean)], Option[(DataType, Boolean)])] = {

    val common = ((schema1.keySet).intersect(schema2.keySet)).map(_.toLowerCase).toList.distinct
    LOGGER.info(" common columns are   " + common.mkString("\n"))

    val distinctkeys = ((schema1.keys) ++ (schema2.keys)).map(_.toLowerCase).toList.distinct
    LOGGER.info("distinctkeys - > " + distinctkeys)
    distinctkeys.flatMap { columnName: String =>
      val schema1FieldOpt: Option[(DataType, Boolean)] = schema1.get(columnName)
      val schema2FieldOpt: Option[(DataType, Boolean)] = schema2.get(columnName)

      if (schema1FieldOpt == schema2FieldOpt) None
      else Some(columnName -> (schema1FieldOpt, schema2FieldOpt))
    }.toMap
  }

  /**
    * getDataFramesWithCommonColumns
    */
  def getDataFramesWithCommonColumns(srcData: DataFrame, targetData: DataFrame) = {
    val schema1 = getMapFromSchema(srcData)
    val schema2 = getMapFromSchema(targetData)
    val common = ((schema1.keySet).intersect(schema2.keySet)).map(_.toLowerCase).toList.distinct
    LOGGER.info(" srcData " + srcData.schema.treeString)
    LOGGER.info(" targetData " + targetData.schema.treeString)
    LOGGER.info(" **** \n\n\n\ncommon columns in source and target are  \n " + common.mkString("\n"))

    val df1 = srcData.selectExpr(common: _*)
    val df2 = targetData.selectExpr(common: _*)
    (df1, df2)
  }

  /**
    * getMapFromSchema -Extract relevant information: name (key), type & nullability (values) of columns
    *
    * @param df
    * @return
    */
  def getMapFromSchema(df: DataFrame): Map[String, (DataType, Boolean)] = {
    val a: Seq[(String, (DataType, Boolean))] = df.schema.map { structField: StructField =>
      structField.name.toLowerCase -> (structField.dataType, structField.nullable)
    }.toList

    a.toMap
  }

  /**
    * columnWiseDifferences - finds columnWise differences between 2 dataframes one is source and another is target
    *
    * @param sourceDataFrame
    * @param targetDataFrame
    * @return
    */

  def columnWiseDifferences(sourceDataFrame: DataFrame, targetDataFrame: DataFrame) = {
    val columns = sourceDataFrame.schema.fields.map(_.name)
        LOGGER.info("source schema")
        sourceDataFrame.printSchema
        LOGGER.info("target schema")
        targetDataFrame.printSchema
    LOGGER.info("Source except target")
    var selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => sourceDataFrame.select(col).except(targetDataFrame.select(col)))

    // columns contains different values.
    selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {
      if (diff.count > 0) diff.show
    })

    selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => targetDataFrame.select(col).except(sourceDataFrame.select(col)))
    LOGGER.info("target except source")

    // columns contains different values.
    selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {
      if (diff.count > 0) diff.show
    })
  }

  /**
    * getListFromSchemaWithKeysOnly -Extract relevant information: name (key) of columns
    *
    * @param df
    * @return
    */
  def getListFromSchemaWithKeysOnly(df: DataFrame): List[String] = {
    val a = df.schema.map { structField: StructField =>
      structField.name.toLowerCase
    }.toList
    a
  }
}
```

Result :

```
2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:48 -  common columns are   id
name
grade
2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:51 - distinctkeys - > List(id, name, grade)
2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:29 - schema differences are  Map(grade -> (Some((StringType,true)),Some((IntegerType,false))))
2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:68 -  srcData root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- grade: string (nullable = true)

2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:69 -  targetData root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- grade: integer (nullable = false)

2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:70 -  **** 



common columns in source and target are  
 id
name
grade
2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:101 - source schema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- grade: string (nullable = true)

2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:103 - target schema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- grade: integer (nullable = false)

2019-05-30 12:44:49 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:105 - Source except target
+-----+
|grade|
+-----+
|     |
+-----+

2019-05-30 12:44:52 INFO  ComparisionUtil$:114 - target except source
+-----+
|grade|
+-----+
|    3|
+-----+
```

> ***Note :*** if you want to use column wise differences in below code snippet, you can ensure that if rowcounts of your oracle tables are
>   not matching then go for it. otherwise columnwisedifferences will take
>   some time if you are using this with large datasets.

if you dont want column wise differences and schema differences you can adapt below approach using `except` on dataframe... for the above dataframes created.

***Option 2 :***

Another option using except which might be simple is 
left hand side except right hand side

```
println("Another option using except which might be simple is ")
    val difference1 = (df1.except(df2))
    println("left hand side except right hand side ")
    difference1.show()
    val difference2 = (df2.except(df1))
    println("right hand side except left hand side ")
    difference2.show()
```

Result :

```
Another option using except which might be simple is 
left hand side except right hand side 
+---+------------+-----+
| id|        name|grade|
+---+------------+-----+
|  2|william peck|     |
|  3|        peck|     |
|  1|         Ram|     |
+---+------------+-----+

right hand side except left hand side 
+---+------------+-----+
| id|        name|grade|
+---+------------+-----+
|  3|        peck|    3|
|  1|         Ram|    3|
|  2|william peck|    3|
+---+------------+-----+
```

Comment: basically I wanted to make sure that i capture the all the rows for comparison some items keep failing unless the feild names are not labeld correctly i do not know what is going on and the speed is slow

Comment: old output is not valid now with new code                                                      
  var df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url", connectionStr)
            .option("dbtable",query1)
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
            .load();            
    //val connectionStr = dbConfigs.getString("connectionstr")
       //var df0 = spark.sql(queryStr0);
       //var df1 = spark.sql(queryStr1); 
       var difference  = df0.unionAll(df1).except(df0.intersect(df1));
       print("SHOW DIFFERENCE..");
       difference.show();